# Define operation for odata routing

Tags: azure-api-management

The goal is to route the service call to internal OData endpoints, but finding a bit tough to get it work, e.g. one operation is to route /odata/customer, if I set the URL template to /odata/customer*, UI complains error 'One or more fields contain incorrect values:' 'URL template is invalid', this could work if URL template is set to /odata/customer/*, however that would require the client call to include the extra / in the request. How would this work out? Thanks!!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll look into that, but I think for the time being you'll have to define two operations for that: "/odata/Customer", and "/odata/Customer/*".